# Report is Slow in SSMS and timing out in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have table that stores about 250K rows of data. the `select *` query takes about 15 seconds to run in SSMS. Rendering the report in SSRS is not working. It just keep loading for about 5 minutes and sometimes works and other times out. Here's my two questions:

1. Is there a way to speed up the select query in SSMS?
2. Is there fix to the issue I'm having in SSRS?

---

1. I have tried converting the query into a stored procedure. Still the same problem in SSRS.
2. I have tried adding a new column to the table which assigns the same id for group of rows based on the date column. i.e. if the year of the date column is 2017 then all rows with this year will have `id column = 1` and if it's 2018 then the `id column = 2`
3. I have tried limiting the number of rows in each page in SSRS but, still no luck.

Comment: Please post the exact SQL query you are using.

Comment: @DaleBurrell it's a select * from table_name

Comment: Firstly, you should always specify the actual columns you want for your report - that ensures you aren't transferring data you don't need, and allows SQL Server to optimise the query. Secondly do you really need 250K rows for a report? That seems unworkable? Thirdly why have you tagged `mysql`?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I'm specifying the column names but I'm selecting everything because I need all of them and I've removed the tag (by mistake)

Comment: Your question shows `select *` its best to be accurate and post your actual query (and table structure for that matter) as that information all makes a difference to the performance.

Comment: And you definitely need all 250K rows? It most likely to be the sheer quantity of data you are trying to move across the network. If your query is as simple as you suggest there isn't much else that would affect performance.

Comment: usually SSRS does not have a problem with number of rows, (because it uses paging), but too many columns can make it very slow.